# How do I add a scroll to sub menu AND a scroll to sub sub menu?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a menu which has parent-child functionality. Such that there'll be categories, sub categories and sub-sub categories.

Like as:

```
main category
- sub category
   - sub of "sub category"
   - sub of "sub category"
- sub category 2
   - sub of "sub category 2"
   - sub of "sub category 2"
```

I've created but when I've added  overflow: scroll; to my sub categories' wrapper, sub-subcategories are not visible.

Have created these two JSFiddle:

Before: http://jsfiddle.net/d1bjnw85/

After: http://jsfiddle.net/z1a88dz1/

I want add scroll to "sub categories" and "sub-sub categories" too.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: you have tried overflow-y:scroll; height:100% ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this? I understand boss' orders but this is terrible UI design and needing a scroll is an indication there's something wrong with the navigation (too many elements), or the website is so complex that a user is going to want to search for where they want to go (say, the Microsoft website).

Comment: yes. i want 2 scrolls.